# SqlConnection.ClearPool() impact on webserver(IIS) performance

Tags: c#, iis, sqlconnection, sqlperformance

I recently monitored my sql database activity I found about 400 processes in activity monitoring.Later I figured that the problem is with my connection string object which would not be cleared physically even though I completely closed and disposed it, so once I suspend my IIS all the processes from activity monitoring would disappear.

after a little searching I found that I can clean all of my connections from application pool so that all the useless processes from SMSS would be killed but

I'm really concerned about it's impact on webserver. It's true that this approach would clear useless tasks from SMSS but for every request a new connection should really be created is it worth it???

considering my application is kind of enterprise app which is supposed to handle to many requests, I'm so afraid of making IIS server down by using this approach.

*Do notice that my connection string value is not completely fixed for all the requeests, I made it variable by changing only "Application Name" section of it in every request according to the request parameters for the purpose of getting requestors information in sql activity monitoring and sql profiler.*

is it worth to do so considering my business scope or it's better I fix the connection string value in other word is performance lag on this approach is so severe that I have to change my logging strategy or it's just a little slower???

Comment: Any attempt to fiddle with the pool will kill performance and is a sign you that the code leaks connections. A lot of connections in the pool is *not* a problem, it means that any new connection requests get server quickly. They *don't* consume anything. On the other hand, 400 active connections means the code forgets to close the connections. Forget the pool. Check the code

Comment: You can starve the pool by varying the connection string. Try not to do that so much. You should not clear the pool, ADO.Net handles it just fine. It is not IIS that will slow down, it is the data access. Keep in mind it is ADO.Net that is managing the pool, not the database.

Comment: BTW connection strings have nothing to do with connections. They are just strings. And connection pooling *is* an enterprise feature, one that allows 400 web requests to be served by just 20 pooled connections, *if* the connections are released as soon as possible.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, connections are created or pulled from the pool based on connection string. [Different connections string will create new connections. Even so much as a blank space will cause this.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_0)

Comment: @Crowcoder I know, and that isn't really the point, unless the OP is using a different username for each connection. Or generating the connection string based on user input. In any case, the issue is with the code/application, not the connection pool

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, ok, I guess you missed that part. OP is varying the connection string.

Comment: After formatting the question, I see that the connection string is modified for the *wrong* reasons. There are other ways to profile and trace performance

Answer (score 1):

> Do notice that my connection string value is not completely fixed for all the requeests, I made it variable by changing only "Application Name" section of it in every request according to the request parameters for the purpose of getting requestors information in sql activity monitoring and sql profiler.

This is really bad because it kills pooling. You might as well disable pooling but that comes with a heavy performance penalty (which you are paying right now already).

Don't do that. Obtain monitoring information in a different way.

Besides that, neither SQL Server nor .NET have a problem with 400 connections. That's unusually high but will not cause problems.

If you run multiple instances of the app (e.g. for HA) this will multiply. The limit is 30k. I'm not aware of any reasons why this would cause a slowdown for the app, but it might cause problems for your monitoring tools.